# Client route for OpenVPN Access Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

I am running OpenVPN Access Server and I'd like to push a route to every client on connection that is the equivalent of:

sudo ip route add 172.17.0.0/24 via 172.27.232.1

Where should I go to set this up (preferably in the OpenVPN AS Web UI)?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the Web UI.
But you can push routes via the vpn in the server config, i.e. in /etc/openvpn/server.conf with the line:
  push route 172.17.0.0 255.255.255.0

Per client configuration can be done in a separate dir (with "client-config-dir client-dir" in the server config).
Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: openvpn AS doesn't have a file at /etc/openvpn/server.conf
There is a config.json at /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/ but I haven't tried just inserting this line in there yet.